# search and replace string

Tags: search, replace, xml

I have a XML tag for example

```
<tag name="abc"></tag>
```

I wanted to replace the string inside "" with the tag name i.e the upper XML tag should be become now

```
<abc name="abc"></abc>
```

Comment: What XML parser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use something like sed/awk for it and use a xml/xslt processor, such as `xmlstarlet` instead.

Create a xslt file with a template such as and save it under transform.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="tag">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can then apply the transformation on your xml document via

```
xmlstarlet tr transform.xsl input.xml
```

Answer (score -1):

Do it as you prefer but here it is:

```
STR='<tag name="abc"></tag>'
AUX=$(echo $STR | cut -d"\"" -f2)
echo $STR | sed "s/tag/$AUX/g"
```

Comment: What about tags like `<tag class="foo" name="abc">`? Or any of the many cases where there may be a `"` before the field you care about? Or tags that span multiple lines with the `name` on a different one? How would this be run on an XML file (which is presumably what the OP has)?

Comment: That is not what the question said. Simply.

Comment: Well, no, but what the question said could be done by `sed 's/name/abc/'` so I think it's safe to assume the situation is a bit more complex than the example shown.